# Xamarin Forms Notifications when app is closed

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, azure-notificationhub

I have a Xamarin Forms app that receives notifications through an Azure Notification Hub. iOS works fine and Android works when the app is in the foreground or background but when the app is closed no notifications occur.

I've noticed that when I close the app any notifications that are there for the app also disappear.

My Android Manifest file is

```
<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="MyApp" android:largeHeap="@bool/largeheap">
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

Is there anything I need to add to my Notification class to make it run when the app is closed as well?

I've tried background services such as what is shown at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/646455/how-to-use-background-service-in-xamarin-android and it doesn't fire when the app is closed.

The code itself for the notification works fine - just needs moved into a background service I guess?

My FirebaseMessagingService class is annotated as a service but doesn't appear to run in the background.

```
[Service(Exported = false)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
```

Any advice would be appreciated!